# How to use toggle to display Html form underneath a particular row Clicked in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML Table. Inside my Html Table I have a php foreach loop to fetch and display data from db into a table(A sample image attached Below). The problem is that I want to display a html form underneath that particular row which I click in that table. But for some reason, which ever row I click the form appears underneath the last Row Only .(A sample image is attached below). I have tried many examples of Jquery but didn't work.[image]
[image]
Here My html and php code:

```
<div class="table-responsive top">
      <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Critility</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date Submitted</th>
            <th>Total Submittions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
          foreach($results as $data){

              echo '<tr  class="dropDown">
                  <td></td>
                  <td>'.$data['Title'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$c.'</td>
                  <td>'.$p.'</td>
                  <td>'.$data['Description'].'</td>
                  <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
                  <td></td>
              </tr>';
          }

        ?>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div id="panel_1" class="dropdown-container">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <fieldset>
            <label>XYZ Questions </label><br>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                <label>YES</label>
            </label>
              <label class="radio-inline left">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                <label>NO</label>
            </label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <label>xyz Questions</label><br>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                <label>YES</label>
              </label>
              <label class="radio-inline left">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                <label>NO</label>
              </label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <label>XYZ Questions</label><br>
              <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                <label>YES</label>
              </label>
            <label class="radio-inline left">
                <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                <label>NO</label>
            </label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
              <label>XYZ Questions</label><br>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                    <label>YES</label>
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline left">
                    <input type="radio" name="optradio">
                    <label>NO</label>
                </label>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And Here is my Script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".dropDown").click(function(){
  $(this).Toggle();
})
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

#### Modifications

**HTML**

- The individual `<form>`s were removed and another one is wrapped around the `.top`
- To demonstrate functionality a real test server is the `action` its response will be displayed in...
- an `iframe[name='response']`

**jQuery**

- `formComp` template literal is moved within function and each radio button pair are assigned a unique `[name]` and a `value`. If checkmarks and radio buttons aren't given a specific value, then it will default to `on`.

---

### Issues

#### Line 6 - Radio Button Groups

The big difference between a check box and a radio button is that a checkbox has two states that can be toggled directly by a user whist the radio button's states must be toggled indirectly by the change of states of another radio button that belongs to the same group. The [name] attribute of a radio button is what associates it with identically named radio buttons.

In the OP there are 4 `<fieldset>`s with 2 radio buttons each. All 8 radio buttons share the same [`name`]:

`<input type="radio" name="optradio">`

The behavior would be that when one of the eight buttons are checked the seven remaining radios will be unchecked. So by the way the `<form>` is designed, I believe having one radio button on and seven of them off wasn't your intention. The solution is simply assign a different [name] for each pair of radio buttons. In the Demo, are 2 `<fieldset>`s, the first pair is:

`<input type="radio" name="optradio0">`

This second pair is:

`<input type="radio" name="optradio1">`

#### Line 15 - #ID Duplication (Possible)

All #id's assigned to elements **MUST BE UNIQUE**. It is my understanding that each row has its own `<form>`. In the OP the `<div>` that is the `<form>`'s parent has an id of `panel_1` which is fine in of itself, but in its current state, it cannot be duplicated without some way of changing the id of each duplicate. If an id is ever duplicated, any JavaScript/jQuery that targets a group of duplicated ids will only work on the first one it finds then ignores the rest.

#### Line 23 to 29 - Table Structure

Table elements have very strict rules about what actually goes where. ***The rules as it applies to OP is:***

**Note:** A parent element has at least one element inside of it. A **child** is a ***direct descendant*** element of a parent element. Any element child of said child and so on, is a *descendant* but not a *child*.

**Parent**     **Child**
`<table>` `<tbody>`
`<tbody>` `<tr>`
`<tr>`   `<td>`
`<td>`   ***ANYTHING***

In short, you cannot put a `<div>` anywhere within a `<table>` with the exception of `<td>`. Placing an element in a `<table>` where it doesn't belong is invalid, furthermore, results will be unexpected, but typically the offending element is pushed out of the `<table>` borders.

---

### Explanation

#### Line 26 - ES6 Template Literals

The syntax of this string is ES6 Template Literal which has a plethora of features. This is a full replacement for literal strings (unless you are concerned with IE). For brevity's sake, this is what's used in the Demo:

**Wrapping text**
- Literal String..: Wrap text in double `<kbd>`"`</kbd>` or single quotes `<kbd>`'`</kbd>`; this becomes very difficult to implement if both types of quotes are needed and/or variables are included.
- Template Literal: Wrap text in backticks ```` <kbd>```</kbd> ````; this allows us to use quotes as a normal character without worrying about mixing or escaping them.

**Concatenation vs. Interpolation**
- Literal String..: Concatenate a variable `'<img src="'+X+'">'`
- Template Literal:  Interpolate a variable `<img src="${X}">`

---

**A cleaner version without comments: [PLUNKER](https://embed.plnkr.co/DWmWqcsDI4pr4GYIwHyP/)**

**Details are commented in Demo**

#### Demo

```js
/* formComp is a shortened version the form from OP because the
|| full version looks too cluttered. Be aware that formComp
|| variable can be of any size and the decision to shorten it was
|| based on aesthetics.
|| The current index number is interpolated into each paired name
|| of each radio button pair.
*/
$('.dropDown').each(function(idx, tr) {

  var formComp = `<fieldset> <legend>XYZ Questions</legend> <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="optradio${idx}0" value='y'> <label>YES</label> </label> <label class="radio-inline left"> <input type="radio" name="optradio${idx}0" value='n'> <label>NO</label> </label> </fieldset> <fieldset> <legend>XYZ Questions</legend> <label class="radio-inline"> <input type="radio" name="optradio${idx}1" value='y'> <label>YES</label> </label> <label class="radio-inline left"> <input type="radio" name="optradio${idx}1" value='n'> <label>NO</label> </label> </fieldset><div class="checkbox" > <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label> </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>`;

  /* Many things are happening on line 22...
  |1. Declaring a jQuery Object with a string in TmpLit syntax
  |2. <tr> has a new class (.colRow)
  |3. <td> is the width of 7 <td>s and occupies the whole <tr>
  |4. <div> set class: .dropdown-container and an id. The id
  ||  is interpolated with the variable idx. var idx is a number
  ||  that is incremented on each loop. For example: if there
  ||  were 3 rows, then there would be <div id='panel_0'>, 
  ||  <div id='panel_1'>, and <div id='panel_2'>. IDs MUST ALWAYS
  ||  BE UNIQUE.
  |5. Then .hide() it
  */
  var newRow = $(`<tr class="colRow"><td colspan="7"><div id="panel_${idx}" class="dropdown-container"></div></td></tr>`).hide();

  // Append the form to newRow
  newRow.find('.dropdown-container').append(formComp);

  // Add the whole thing AFTER the tr.dropDown
  $(this).after(newRow);
});

/* Whenever a tr.dropDown is clicked...
|| find the proceeding sibling tr.colRow and toggle it on/off
*/
$('.dropDown').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.colRow').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 100, 0.7);
}

tr.colRow:hover {
  cursor: default;
  background: initial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    tr:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 100, 0.7);
    }
    
    tr.colRow:hover {
      cursor: default;
      background: initial;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<!--
form#main on submit event will send data to test server. The 
response will be diplayed in an iframe at the bottom of this page
-->
 <form id='main' action='https://httpbin.org/post?' method='post' target='response'>
    <div class="table-responsive top">
      <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Critility</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Date Submitted</th>
            <th>Total Submittions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr class="dropDown">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td>Do you mean: Criticality?</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>02-03-18</td>
            <td>It's spelt: Submissions</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="dropDown">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Title 2</td>
            <td>Do you mean: Criticality?</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>02-03-18</td>
            <td>It's spelt: Submissions</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="dropDown">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Title 3</td>
            <td>Do you mean: Criticality?</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>02-03-18</td>
            <td>It's spelt: Submissions</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="dropDown">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Title 4</td>
            <td>Do you mean: Criticality?</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>02-03-18</td>
            <td>It's spelt: Submissions</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="dropDown">
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Title 5</td>
            <td>Do you mean: Criticality?</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>X</td>
            <td>02-03-18</td>
            <td>It's spelt: Submissions</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form> 
  <!--
  form#main has a [target='response'] which directs the form to
  redirectserver response to an iframe[name='response']
  -->
  <iframe name='response' src='about:blank' width='500' height='250'></iframe>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 3 WORDS. YOU ARE AMAZING . Thank you so much. I was trying this from past 2 days.Much appreciated. Thank you again

Comment: My pleasure,  it looks like you're trying and if you understood the overlooked yet critical discrepancies, you can move forward.  Happy coding.

Comment: I am facing an another problem with it. Whenever I submit a form of a particular row the values of each row get change.Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Sachjot. Did you add the PHP back into the code? I had to remove the PHP to demonstrate the frontend side functioning. Try using your HTML with the PHP and then add the differences between the new HTML and new HTML but leave your PHP and then modify it so it reproduces the new PHP. I'm a front-end developer so my knowledge server side is lacking. If that doesn't work you'll have to post a new question and add PHP tag to it.

Comment: I took a closer look and I think I know the problem. Each row is a `<form>` so in the `formComp` remove the `<form>` tag (both ends)`</form>` Then wrap that `<form>` tag around the whole table. I'm working right now, but I'll be back to modify the answer later.

Comment: Oh ok, Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @Sachjot See update, I added a real test server so you can submit the form from this site or plunker and the response will be displayed in an iframe at the bottom of form.